# Best js practices Setting a flag, override vs check

Tags: javascript, flags

this is a simple one if a have a function that is gonna be called to detect a change in a settings page like.

```
hasChanged: function (){
    flag = true;
}
```

But the user can keep changing stuff and call this function lots of times. it's better to call it always (and set again the boolean) rather than

```
hasChanged: function (){
    if(!flag)
       flag = true;
}
```

other solution could be a validation that prevents the call to this function. But anyway is gonna be a function and an overkill.

This is something really simple, but I'm curious about it . . . docs, links, books, and stuff are appreciated for your answers.

thanks,

Comment: I don't understand what value the `if` check would have.  Also, what if they change something and then change it back?  Should the flag still be true?

Comment: Mlstalis, well could be a 'performance' preference in someone or a best practice in compilation or whatever, but yeah, could be just preference.

stephen, mi concern is not about logic, mi concern is about best practice :)  but thanks !

Comment: If the logic is superfluous and/or erroneous then how could it be best practice?

Comment: stephen, when i said 'not about logic' i mean, that the code has the logic that i want and works as expected.

And my question is about something else :) but i agrere with you. There's no point to have a best practice without an erroneous logic, but actually with a superfluous one, it could be . . . an example of this is just a couple of duplicated simple logic that you can DRY to an abstract function with params.

Comment: The only way this superfluous `if` could be a good practice, much less a best practice, were if it were somehow vastly more performant to do the if check before the set.  However, even then, I would guess that the odds of this being an important optimization are very very low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's a bad practice to toggle a variable that is in the global namespace or window object, to avoid side-effects.

So, instead of

```
hasChanged: function () {
  if (!window.flag) {
     window.flag = true
  }
}
```

You should do,

```
hasChanged: function (flag) {
  if (!flag) {
     flag = true
  }
  return flag
}
```

Second, you can simplify and minify to:

```
hasChanged: function (flag) {
  return !flag
}
```

or, if you're using > ES2016, a one line:

```
hasChanged: (flag) => !flag
```

Which means, that in case flag is false, it'll return true.

Comment: i appreciate your full context on the question, but the usage of variables are not in the scope of the question; also im not toggling a var, im setting it to true when something happened.

im just asking if there's a better or prefered way to do it and avoid setting it again, if the value is the same.